# Why is Fibonacci iterative slower than the recursive version (with memoization)?

Tags: python, time-complexity

I'm comparing two versions of the Fibonacci routine in Python 3:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache()
def fibonacci_rec(target: int) -> int:

    if target < 2:
        return target

    res = fibonacci_rec(target - 1) + fibonacci_rec(target - 2)

    return res


def fibonacci_it(target: int) -> int:

    if target < 2:
        return target

    n_1 = 2
    n_2 = 1

    for n in range(3, target):

        new = n_2 + n_1
        n_2 = n_1
        n_1 = new

    return n_1
```

The first version is recursive, with memoization (thanks to `lru_cache`). The second is simply iterative.

I then benchmarked the two versions and I'm slightly surprised by the results:

```
In [5]: %timeit fibonacci_rec(1000)
82.7 ns ± 2.94 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit fibonacci_it(1000)
67.5 µs ± 2.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

The iterative version is waaaaay slower than the recursive one. Of course the first run of the recursive version will take lots of time (to cache all the results), and the recursive version takes more memory space (to store all the calls). But I wasn't expecting such difference on the runtime. Don't I get some overhead by calling a function, compared to just iterating over numbers and swapping variables?

Comment: I am curious why the recursive variant runs on 10m loops, probably has nothing with the result but it is quite high value

Comment: The difference comes from the value of the parameter. The cached version just does a cache lookup each time. The iterative version does 1000 loops. Try different parameters, perhaps 100, 10000 or 100000.

Comment: just curious: I reach max recursion depth when calling the recursive version with 1000 (495 seems the max. for me), although my stacklimit is set to 1000. Anyone got an idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see, `timeit` invokes the function many times, to get a reliable measurement. The LRU cache of the recursive version is not being cleared between invocations, so after the first run, `fibonacci_rec(1000)` is just returned from the cache immediately without doing any computation.

Comment: Aaaaaah, I see what's happening. `fibonacci(1000)` will be cached and re-used after the first time timeit will have run it. Thanks. I added a better benchmark in my question that proves you're right.

Comment: @JPFrancoia It's not good to edit the question in such a way that it contains its own answer; better to post your corrected benchmark as a separate answer.

Comment: Thanks, I posted the better benchmark as a new answer. Sorry I wasn't aware of how to do this particular thing.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @Thomas, the cache isn't cleared between invocations of `fibonacci_rec` (so the result of `fibonacci(1000)` will be cached and re-used). Here is a better benchmark:

```
def wrapper_rec(target: int) -> int:

    res = fibonacci_rec(target)

    fibonacci_rec.cache_clear()

    return res


def wrapper_it(target: int) -> int:

    res = fibonacci_it(target)

    # Just to make sure the comparison will be consistent
    fibonacci_rec.cache_clear()

    return res
```

And the results:

```
In [9]: %timeit wrapper_rec(1000)
445 µs ± 12.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit wrapper_it(1000)
67.5 µs ± 2.46 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```